# How to get the deleted git repository back?

Tags: git, repository

I've deleted my local repository by mistake, how do I get the files back from remote repository ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply clone ([`git clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)) back your repo

```
git clone /url/of/remote/repo
```

But that won't include the files that were being modified, or just added to the local index.